# Proper Syntax highlighting with Eclipse + WDT + Javascript 1.7+

Tags: javascript, eclipse, syntax-highlighting

Is it possible to make the Eclipse-Javascript-Editor recognise Mozillas JS 1.7 constructs and do the syntax highlighting properly?

Examples:

- "let", "for each", "yield" are not highlighted
- No support for E4X

I'm using an updated Helios + WDT-Plugin and I can't choose a different validator than ECMAScript3.

I tried to find some information on the eclipse.org, a plan or something, but that website always drives me crazy. oh my...

Answer (score -1):

In the IDE right-click the file and select "Open with JavaScript Editor.   The IDE should use the syntax highlighting set by the IDE.

If you simply open the file or open with text editor the workspace is not syntax-aware and will not employ color coding.